# accepting and using char in a condition statement

Tags: c++

Hi i'm currently reviewing my basic programming, in this code i'm trying to get the average of `3` grades but it doesn't accept a character as an input and jumps to the end of the program after entering `Y` or `y`. any help would be appreciated :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int g1,g2,g3;
int AVG = (g1+g2+g3)/3;

int main ()
{
    cout << " Hi! Do you want to calculate the average? (Y/N)?";
    char a;
    cin >> a;
    if ((a == 'Y' && a == 'y'))
     {
       cout << "Enter three grades \n";
       cin >> g1 >> g2 >> g3;
       cout << "Your average grade is : " << AVG;
     }
    else 
     {
       cout << "THANK YOU!";
     }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about your condition a little while... The value of `a` can't be both `'Y'` and `'y'` *at the same time*.

Comment: Use `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: Also (but unrelated to your problem), you have a bad habit: Global variables. There's no need for `g1`, `g2`, `g3` or `AVG` to be global. Even worse, the value of `AVG` is calculated *before* you get the value of `g1`, `g2` and `g3`. Calculations aren't redone retroactively.

Comment: C++ is not a declarative programming language. Some languages may allow you to declare `AVG` as the average of `g1` to `g3`. But C++ doesn't work that way. You merely calculate something and store it in `AVG`.

Comment: thank you for your correction :) i honestly have fuzzy foundation about this i'm glad a community like this exists.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, use `||` instead of `&&` in `if` condition.  like :

```
if ((a == 'Y' || a == 'y'))
```

Also, do average operation after getting user input. like :

```
if ((a == 'Y' || a == 'y'))
{
       cout << "Enter three grades \n";
       cin >> g1 >> g2 >> g3;
       AVG = (g1+g2+g3)/3; // <========= here
       cout << "Your average grade is : " << AVG;
}
```

In C and C++, cut off the decimal expansion when dividing two integers. Since `5 / 2 = 2.5`, it cuts off the `.5` and print only `2`.

> [C++11: 5.6/4]: The binary `/` operator yields the quotient, and the
>   binary `%` operator yields the remainder from the division of the first
>   expression by the second. If the second operand of `/` or `%` is zero the
>   behavior is undefined. **For integral operands the `/` operator yields the
>   algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded;** if the quotient
>   a/b is representable in the type of the result, `(a/b)*b + a%b` is equal
>   to a.

Comment: Will upvote if you caution the OP about the pitfalls of integer division.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you sir. I have added.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
if ((a == 'Y' && a == 'y'))
```

You need to use the `||` operator,  not the `&&`.

Comment: @SamD Actually it solved only the part of the problem. Your average will always evaluate to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the variable `AVG` declared like

```
int AVG = (g1+g2+g3)/3;
```

in the global scope is always equal to 0 because it is not changed in the program.

There is no need to declare these variables AVG, g1, g2, g3 in the global scope. Each variable should be declared in the point where it is used.

Also an object can not be equal simultaneously to two different values. So this condition

```
if ((a == 'Y' && a == 'y'))
```

is wrong. You mean (I've indulged myself in removing the superfluous parentheses)

```
if (a == 'Y' || a == 'y')
```

Taking all this into account the program can look for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Hi! Do you want to calculate the average (Y/N)? ";

        char c;

        if ( not ( std::cin >> c ) or not ( c == 'Y' || c == 'y' ) ) 
        {
            std::cout << "THANK YOU!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }           

        std::cout << "\nEnter three grades: ";

        int x, y, z;

        std::cin >> x >> y >> z;

        std::cout << "Your average grade is : " << ( x + y + z ) / 3  << "\n\n"; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Hi! Do you want to calculate the average (Y/N)? y
Enter three grades: 1 5 6 
Your average grade is : 4

Hi! Do you want to calculate the average (Y/N)? n
THANK YOU!
```